# Is there a way to scale up and scale down executors in spark application at runtime by program instead of dynamic allocation?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-streaming

I am running my application on kubernetes environemnt.
I have a limitation where I can't go with dynamic allocation as it will introduce lot of runtime variables in to application running instance like shuffling, GC, etc. I want to start the spark application with bare minimum number of executors. Based on certain parameters and watchers (can include spark listeners here to collect load metrics), I want to scale the executors count up or down without restarting the spark job.

Is there a way to achieve this in spark running on kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by setting the conf (spark.executor.instances) at runtime and the restarting the spark context:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("my_app").set("spark.executor.instances", "3")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
...
conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "6")
sc.stop()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```